# Creating curryable functions with lambdas in D doesn't work as class\struct memebers

Tags: lambda, d, currying

I've been playing around with D, trying to mimic [Scala style curryable functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/135) by chaining lambda expressions.

I came up with this:

```cpp
immutable foo=function(immutable int x)=>(immutable int y)=>(x+y);
struct S
{
    static immutable foo=function(immutable int x)=>(immutable int y)=>(x+y);
}
class C     static immutable foo=function(immutable int x)=>(immutable int y)=>(x+y);
}

void main()
{
    writefln("global\t%s",foo(1)(2));
    writefln("struct\t%s",S.foo(1)(2));
    writefln("class\t%s",C.foo(1)(2));
}
```

This is what I get when I run it:

```
global  3
struct  1528543170
Segmentation fault
```

As you can see, my method works well for the global function variable, but the struct's static function variable gives junk result, and the class's static function variable fails completely.
If I remove the `x` from the return expression - `function(immutable int x)=>(immutable int y)=>(y)` - the struct version gives the correct result(`2`), but the class version still fails.

If I use a regular method, instead of a function variable:

```cpp
immutable foo=function(immutable int x)=>(immutable int y)=>(x+y);
struct S
{
    static auto foo(immutable int x)
    {
        return (immutable int y)=>(x+y);
    }
}
class C
{
    static auto foo(immutable int x)
    {
        return (immutable int y)=>(x+y);
    }
}

void main()
{
    writefln("global\t%s",foo(1)(2));
    writefln("struct\t%s",S.foo(1)(2));
    writefln("class\t%s",C.foo(1)(2));
}
```

it works just fine:

```
global  3
struct  3
class   3
```

And I also get the advantage of using delegates(the compiler won't allow delegates in the first version) - but this style is less elegant.

I am well aware that D has the `curry` function in the `std.functional` library for currying functions, but sometimes it's more comfortable to make a function curryable by default, and beside - I'm curious to know why my first version doesn't work.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

OK, [I've filed a bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=8227). I've done some more digging, and it turns out the argument list of `foo` gets shifted, and that's why `x` gets junk data.

Comment: WHOA you can say `function` *and* say `=>` at the same time?! Didn't know that! :)

Comment: By the way, did you try saying `static __gshared` instead of `static` by any chance? *Maybe* it'll work (fingers crossed... I don't have a compiler handy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, it looks like you ran into a compiler bug. [Please report it](http://d.puremagic.com/issues). Since the variables in the struct and class are static, their behavior should be identical to that of the module-level variable, and clearly, it's not.

Comment: It really is a compiler bug. I narrowed it down some more and reported it.